# Exists a way to let crawlers ignore parts of a document?

Tags: javascript, html, seo, web-crawler

I am aware that you can control which documents a crawler/spider can access by robots.txt, meta tags, link attributes and so on.

But in my special case I want just a portion of a document being ignored. That portion can not exist in an IFrame, but is moreover "normal" content. Something like `<noscript>` blocks would be amazing, that mark partial content as *"Don't index this, please."*

- First, I thought about using `document.write()` to write out those parts, but I learned that my assumption "spiders generally do not execute JavaScript" seems to be wrong.
- I was thinking about serving a different version of the page when I detect a crawler, but this is not very accurate, right?
- Also, I can not put that content on an image.

Are there any tricks to avoid getting a specific part of a document (not some specific words spread around the document) indexed?

**[edit]** I know I could do some "If user agent is in a list of robots", but I don't like that idea. Possibly there is a more agnostic approach. The part to be suppressed contains dynamic content and whatever I am doing, it has to work with "old" browsers like IE6 :\

Comment: use innerHTML from external js file

Comment: Sounds like it could work, I have to fiddle around with that:) I dislike the complexity involved, because the part to suppress contains dynamic content:\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only difference between static content and dynamic content is the extension of the file you include:

```
var extension = "js"; // change to "php" for example to load dynamic content
function loadJS(filename){
  var js=document.createElement('script')
  js.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  js.setAttribute("src", filename)
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js);
}
window.onload=function() {
  loadJS("somecontenttoload."+extension); // hard for crawlers to read 
}
```

in somecontenttoload.js:

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML="This is static";
```

in somecontenttoload.php

```
<?PHP 
  header("content-type:text/javascript");
  // load data from database
  $bla = .....;
  ?>
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML="<? echo $bla; ?>";
```

Comment: That's cool, what I meant by dynamic content is just that it adds some more complexity to the dynamic code. But it looks like this really is the way to go. I can even wrap the first output block to already be omitted when the user agent definitively is a bot...